# Issue combining inner and outer joins in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to simplify a query against an Oracle database that uses multiple inner joins against the same table. I know the multiple joins against the same table can be cleaned up with outer joins, but I'm failing to elicit the same results.

Below are the tables listing only the columns needed for the query. The "link" column in table X maps to the ID, ID2, and ID3 columns in tables A, B, and C respectively.

```
**Table A**
id

**Table B**
id
id2
nm

**Table C**
id3
nm

**Table X**
cfgnum
link
```

Existing (working query):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A,
     X,
     X X1,
     X X2,
     B,
     C
WHERE X.cfgnum = 9999
AND A.id = X.link
AND X.cfgnum = X1.cfgnum
AND X.cfgnum = X2.cfgnum
AND B.id2 = X1.link
AND B.id = A.id
AND C.id3 = X2.link
AND C.nm = B.nm;
```

The below was my attempt to rewrite, but it returns substantially different results. With the comments in place it does return the right number of rows against the linking X table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM X
LEFT JOIN A ON X.link = A.id
LEFT JOIN B on X.link = B.id2 --AND A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN C on X.link = C.id3 --AND B.nm = C.nm
WHERE cfgnum = 9999
AND COALESCE (A.id, B.id2, C.id3) IS NOT NULL;
```

Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Apologies, new at this, and it appears I did not provide enough information. Table X groups rows from other tables under a "cfgnum". Each "cfgnum" can link to numerous rows in numerous tables.

Hopefully the below sample data makes sense.

```
**Table A**
id
1
2
7
    
**Table B**
id  id2  nm
3   1    name1
4   3    name2
    
**Table C**
id3  nm
5    name2
6    name3
    
**Table X**
cfgnum  link
9998    1
9998    2
9998    3
9999    1
9999    3
9999    4
9999    6
9999    7
9999    8
```

My thought was using left joins to X would minimize the number of joins required to X. Notice the "working" query has X three times in the from clause. If I'm offbase, please let me know.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.  You apparently know something that I do not ("I know the multiple joins against the same table can be cleaned up with outer joins") so an explanation of that would also be helpful.  I would also recommend asking questions only with proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: "With the comments in place it does return the right number of rows against the linking X table." - I don't think it returns correct number of rows. More looks like a coincidence

Comment: @GordonLinoff, please let me know if this isn't what you were requesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are no left joins in your previous query. So you can try this -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM A
  JOIN X ON A.id = X.link
  JOIN X1 ON X.cfgnum = X1.cfgnum
  JOIN X2 ON X.cfgnum = X2.cfgnum
  JOIN B ON B.id2 = X1.link
         AND B.id = A.id
  JOIN C ON C.id3 = X2.link
         AND C.nm = B.nm
WHERE X.cfgnum = 9999
```

Comment: Understood, but the goal was to eliminate having to use X1 and X2. I believed using left joins would allow me to remove them.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the original query. X1 and X2 are aliases for table X. Thank you!

Comment: I have again edited my question to hopefully provide more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
If you have just one-to-one relationship, ie you have just 1 link to each of A,B,C for specific cfgnum, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (select cfgnum,
        max(decode(rownum,1,link)) link1,
        max(decode(rownum,2,link)) link2,
        max(decode(rownum,3,link)) link3
      from X
      WHERE cfgnum = 9999
      group by cfgnum -- just in case if you need to remove the predicate "cfgnum=9999"
    ) x1
    join A on A.id in (link1,link2,link3)
    join B on B.id2 in (link1,link2,link3) and B.id = A.id
    join C on C.id3 in (link1,link2,link3) and C.nm = B.nm;
```

Comment: Your two ANDs in the JOINs provides the same result as my query with the ANDs commented.

Comment: @Kimmel sorry, I misread your question. Please read the update

Comment: I have hopefully provided more clarification to my question.

Comment: @Kimmel have you checked the updated answer?

Comment: I did. As my above data shows there are many links between the tables. I did not thoroughly explain that in my original post.